# Schengen Visa Italy: i94 meets 3 month criteria but visa expires 10 days prior

Tags: schengen-visas, us-citizens, italy, 90-180-visa-rules

I am applying for Schengen Visa through Italian consulate in San Francisco. The 90-day criteria for leaving the Schengen area with valid US stay is fulfilled exactly by I-94 date but the stamped H1 visa expires in 80 days. All the other docs are in order.

Any suggestions as to if this will work or should I change something?

Answer (score 2):

The US visa expiry date is irrelevant for remaining in the US. It is the last date for entering the US with that visa. What is relevant is whether you are in status, and your I-94 will show that.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Hopefully they will validate the stay as per i94 instead of visa.